# Apparent contradiction to Poincaré lemma?

Tags: differential-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

I have learned that, if we have a connected, oriented and compact n-dimensional manifold, the top de Rham cohomology is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e
$$ H_{\text{dR}}^n(M) \cong \mathbb{R}.$$
However, Poincaré's lemma states that for any star-shaped subset of $ \mathcal{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, it holds that
$$ {H_{\text{dR}}^k(\mathcal{U}) = 0} \qquad \text{for all }k \neq 0.$$

Consider now the ball of radius $1$, this is evidently star shaped. Furthermore, it seems to me that it also suffices the properties in the first result. What is wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: In just the topological setting, the idea is that because $\mathcal U$ is star-shaped, it is _contractible_ – i.e. it can be continuously deformed to a point, and because (singular) cohomology is invariant under such continuous deformations, the (singular) cohomology of $\mathcal U$ must be that of a point, i.e. trivial for all $k \neq 0$. I suspect something similar is true in the de Rham setting?

Comment: In your first statement you listed the property 'connected' twice. Is that a typo and is there a property missing?

Comment: one problem with the open ball is that although it is _bounded,_ it is not compact?

Comment: Yes, it had to be compact. Thanks!

Comment: Oh dear, thanks Rylee.. I don't know how I screwed that one up..

Comment: There is an additional assumption needed to conclude $H^n(M)\cong \mathbb{R}$:  $M$ must have no boundary.  This fails in your ball example, if you take the closed ball.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the statement in the form: "top de-Rham cohomology of compact, connected, oriented manifold without boundary is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: That's where I made my mistake. I swapped books, where in the first one a manifold is defined without boundary, and in the second one it is defined with boundary. Thank you very much!